# deletecollection kubernetes (tekton) resources - specific RBAC needed?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am trying to delete [tekton](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline) kubernetes resources in the context of a service account with an on-cluster kubernetes config, and am experiencing errors specific to accessing `deletecollection` with all tekton resources. An example error is as follows:

> pipelines.tekton.dev is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-account:default" cannot deletecollection resource "pipelines" in API group "tekton.dev" in the namespace "my-namespace"

I have tried to apply [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) to help here, but continue to experience the same errors. My RBAC attempt is as follows:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-role
  namespace: my-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["tekton.dev"]
  resources: ["pipelines", "pipelineruns", "tasks", "taskruns"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "delete", "deletecollection"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-role-binding
  namespace: my-namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:my-account:default
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

These RBAC configurations continue to result in the same error. Is this, or similar necessary? Are there any examples of RBAC when interfacing with, specifically deleting, tekton resources?

Answer (score 3):

Given two namespaces `my-namespace` and `my-account` the default service account in the `my-account` namespace is correctly granted permissions to the `deletecollection` verb on `pipelines` in `my-namespace`.

You can verify this using `kubectl auth can-i` like this after applying:

```
$ kubectl -n my-namespace --as="system:serviceaccount:my-account:default" auth can-i deletecollection pipelines.tekton.de
yes
```

Verify that you have actually applied your RBAC manifests.

Answer (score -1):

Change the RBAC as below

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: my-role
  namespace: my-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["tekton.dev"]
  resources: ["pipelines", "pipelineruns", "tasks", "taskruns"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "delete", "deletecollection"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-rolebinding
  namespace: my-namespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: my-account
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: my-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Few things to note:

1. Fixed `subjects` to use `ServiceAccount` from `User`. This is actually the cause of the failure because the service account was not granted the RBAC.
2. I assumed that you want to delete the Tekton resources in `my-namespace` by the `default` service account of `my-account` namespace . If it's different then changes in `Role` and `RoleBinding` need to be done accordingly.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Your changes grant the default service account in the `my-account` namespace cluster-wide permissions. It is irrelevant if you use a Role or a ClusterRole. But to grant cross-namespace permissions simply use a RoleBinding in the target namespace, that refers to a subject in another namespace.

Also, deletecollection is a valid verb.